# What do I do when the terminal says "Check the logs for full command output"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When I type `pip install pygame` or `pip3 install pygame` on terminal, it says "check the logs for full command output". I already upgraded pip and it still says that. Can you tell me what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: We nee more details : can you please post here the exact output of the command ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try running the `pip` command by adding the `--verbose` flag. This will print out the logs in the Terminal, which you then can inspect. These logs often help you indicate the cause of the error.

For example:

`pip install --verbose pygame`

or

`pip3 install --verbose pygame`

Answer (score 0):

When you get this message, there will be a few lines above it which tell you where the log file is and some more details about what went wrong.